# Retrieve number of columns in SQL Table - C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm very new to C#. I'm trying to retrieve the number of columns using:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sys.columns
```

Could you please explain how to use the command and put it into a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string connectionString =
            "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;"
            + "Integrated Security=true";

        // Provide the query string with a parameter placeholder.
        string queryString =
            "SELECT Count(*) from sys.columns";

        // Specify the parameter value.
        int paramValue = 5;

        // Create and open the connection in a using block. This
        // ensures that all resources will be closed and disposed
        // when the code exits.
        using (SqlConnection connection =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

            // Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
            // Create and execute the DataReader, writing the result
            // set to the console window.
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}",
                        reader[0]);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I convert the number of columns to an integer for use in a random command?

Comment: @liamp47, look at others(Darren Davies,aleroot,gout) answers all of them had converted.

Answer (score 4):

To connect to the database you can use the `SqlConnection` class and then to retrieve the Row Count you can use the `Execute Scalar` function.  An example from MSDN:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM sys.columns;";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection

Comment: he's asking for the column count, not the row count.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use `ExecuteScalar` as the others have said. Also, you will need to filter your `SELECT` on the `object_id` column to get the columns **in a particular table**.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'table_name')
```

Alternatively, you could do worse than familiarise yourself with the [ANSI-standard `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) to find the same information in a future-proof, cross-RDBMS way.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a command and retrieve back the scalar variable :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

use Executescalar() for getting a single element.

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) //for connecting to database
            {
                con.Open();
                try
                {
                    using (SqlCommand getchild = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from table1 ", con)) //SQL queries
                    {
                        Int32 count = (Int32)getchild.ExecuteScalar();
                     }
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

```
Int32 colnumber = 0;
string sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM sys.columns";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        colnumber = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the ADO .NET functions in the System.Data.SqlClient namespace. ExecuteScalar is an easy-to-use method when you only want to get a single result. For multiple results, you can use a SqlDataReader.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
string resultVar = String.Empty;
string ServerName="localhost";
string DatabaseName="foo";
        SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI",ServerName,DatabaseName));
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(Query,conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (SqlException se)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format(
                "Connection error: {0} Num:{1} State:{2}",
                se.Message,se.Number, se.State));
        }
        resultVar = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: There is no need to cast as (string) after calling ToString().