# How to count columns of SQL Server 2008's table using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am developing an application in C# in Visual Studio 2008. I connected a SQL Server 2008 database with it.

I want to count the number of columns so that I can loop around them to get the particular data.

I can figure it out columns by going to the database but I am joing 4-5 tables in my programs so I want to know if I can count the columns.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thank you
Shyam

Comment: How are you connecting to the DB? Linq2Sql, ADO.NET, EF?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can get a list of tables, columns, etc. by examining the database catalog (e.g. `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`), but it sounds like you already know that. It's unclear what the question is here.

Comment: _"I want to count the number of columns so that i can loop around them to get the particular data"_ I think you're doing things wrong. You can select all columns you need in one step: `SELECT T1Col1=T1.col1,T2Col1=T2.col1,col2,col3 From T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.Col1=T2.Col1`. There is no need to loop.

Comment: This is similiar question with answer [CountOfColumns][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699166/retrieve-number-of-columns-in-sql-table-c-sharp

Comment: Thank You Guys
you guys are really helpful.
I learned lot of  different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
```

Comment: But how can you store that number in one variable in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'yourTable'
```

See [this page provided wy TaronPro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699166/retrieve-number-of-columns-in-sql-table-c-sharp) to know how to retrieve the result.

Comment: Or even without the join: `FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourTable');`

Comment: Thanks for fast responces.
@Yuck the question is how can i get that number of all the columns.
I am using SELECT COUNT(*) From sys.columns but it just select it not give me that number. how can i get the number?
I am new with SQL SERVER and C# too.

Comment: See what @TaronPro suggested : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699166/retrieve-number-of-columns-in-sql-table-c-sharp

Comment: `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
           con.Open();
           using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Status", con))
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString()+"\t"+reader[1].ToString()+"\t"+reader[2].ToString()+"\t"+reader[3].ToString());
                   
                }
            }
        }`
This is my code

Comment: This is not I wanted but still i learned something.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQLConnection object to connect to DB, use its GetSchema method to get list of all columns without querying.

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   {
       // Connect to the database then retrieve the schema information.
       connection.Open();
       DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
        ..
        ..
        ..
```

If you want to know columns for specific owner, table or table type, use restriction within GetSchema method.

```
    string[] restrictions = new string[4];
    restrictions[1] = "dbo";
    DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);
```

for more information refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in a similar situation is that when I executed the query I retrieved all the data into a DataSet.

When I got the DataSet I opened the first table (ds.Tables[0]). Obviously you check first for existance.

When you have the table then its as simple as performing a

```
dt.Columns.Count;
```

In summary DS.Tables[0].Columns.Count
To find a specific column by name you loop through and find the one that

```
for (z=0; z < dt.Columns.Count; z++)
{
  // check to see if the column name is the required name passed in.
  if (dt.Columns[z].ColumnName == fieldName)
  {
    // If the column was found then retrieve it 
    //dc = dt.Columns[z];
    // and stop looking the rest of the columns
    requiredColumn = z;
    break;
 }
```

}

Then to find the data you need I would then loop through the rows of the table and get the field for that column...
ie...

```
string return = dr.Field<string>(requiredColumn);
```

Probalby not the best way of doing it but it works. Obviously if the data contained in the field is not string then you need to pass the appropriate type...

```
dr.Field<decimal>(requiredColumn)
dr.Field<int>(requiredColumn)
```

etc

Rgds
George

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast responses.

Answer (score 0):

The reader itself gives you the number of columns. This is useful when you don't want to know the number rows of a specific table or view but from an ad-hoc query.

You can dump the columns like this

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM my query";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",
                              reader.GetName(i),
                              reader.IsDBNull(i) ? "NULL" : reader.GetValue(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` namespace to get the number of columns in a specified table as follows
1 . add Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo dll in your project and use the namespace Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
2 . write the follwing code

```
private int colCount()
{
      Server server=new Server(".\\SQLEXPRESS");
      Database database=Server.Databases["your database name"];
      Table table=database.Tables["your table name"];
      return (table.Columns.Count);
}
```